# auto insert when update a table cell

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. One of them has a column which saves agreement details. When user updates the agreement detail, I want to insert updated value and date into another table. I mean
when I update a table cell, I want to insert the updated value into another table. Also, inserting updated date may be useful. Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use mysql triggers to do that. Learn more about that [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html).